# Непонятная конструкция es6

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

Пытаюсь разобраться во vuex. Впервые увидел эту конструкцию es6:

```
export const mutations = {
  [types.INIT_JOKES](state, payload) {
    state.jokes.push(...payload);
  }
};
```

Что это такое внутри объекта `mutations`?

А именно: `[types.INIT_JOKES](state, payload) {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это называется [вычисляемые имена свойств](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-object#%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)

```js
let key = "z";
let obj = { [key]: "test" };
console.log(obj.z);
```

В вашем случае таким образом задается метод:

```js
const key = "z";
const obj = { 
  [key](t){
    return t;
  } 
}
console.log(obj.z("test"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Это объявление функции с именем указанным в переменной `types.INIT_JOKES`. ES6 так позволяет писать.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const state = {
 jokes: []
}

const types = {
 INIT_JOKES: 'INIT_JOKES'
}

const mutations = {
  [types.INIT_JOKES](state, payload) {
    state.jokes.push(...payload)
    console.log(state.jokes)
  }
}

mutations.INIT_JOKES(state, [1,2,3])
```